# Why are my drawn bounding boxes inverted?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, python-tesseract

I think I am missing some really simple concept or perhaps not understanding the directions in which things are read/drawn by either PIL.ImageDraw or the output created by pytesseract...In any case my question is "Why are my bounding boxes inverted?"

Example code as follows:
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output

```
input_image = Image.open('input_sample.jpg')
tess_boxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(input_image,output_type=Output.DICT)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(input_image)

for idx,character in enumerate(tess_boxes['char']):

    #Get each point needed to draw the box
    left = tess_boxes['left'][idx]
    right = tess_boxes['right'][idx]
    bottom = tess_boxes['bottom'][idx]
    top = tess_boxes['top'][idx]

    #Re-arranging these seem to have no effect
    # y = (left,top)
    # x = (right,bottom)
    # runs the same as the following: 
    y = (right,bottom)
    x = (left,top)

    #Swapping x and y here has no visible effect
    draw.rectangle((x,y),fill=None,outline="#FF0000",width=3)

input_image.save('output_sample.png', "PNG")
```

Input Image
[image: Sample input image to be marked with bounding boxes]

Output Image
[image: sample output with inverted bounding boxes]

Comment: You seem to have a mismatch between libraries that treat the Y coordinate as increasing going up (as is the convention in mathematics) and that treat the Y coordinate as increasing going down (as is common in computer graphics, since monitors always scan downwards).

Comment: I agree with you @jasonharper , I am just stumped as far as how to fix it.

I am not finding information on PIL or pytesseract regarding which direction they scan.

On this note I am going to have PIL draw from 0,0 to 10,10 and see if pytess has any drawing abilities itself to do the same thing. That should visually show me what is going on I suppose.

Any advisements are appreciated :)

I mean...Aside from the inversion, it works great! lol

Comment: Just subtract each Y value from the height of the image before using it.

Comment: @jasonharper ... You friend deserve a cookie ... I was so tunnel visioned into the problem I completely bypassed that simple bit of logic. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `image_to_data`. You don't need to do arithmetic operations.

```py
import pytesseract

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("cRPKk.jpg")

# Convert to gray-scale
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# OCR
d = pytesseract.image_to_data(gry, output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)
n_boxes = len(d['level'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'][i], d['height'][i])
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant thank you for the additional method. Regarding the use of "image_to_data" versus "image_to_boxes" , may I assume that "image_to_data" reads in a different direction than the "Boxes" option? 

Thank you again for the variation solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

PyTesseract and PIL "scan" in different directions so the Y coordinates were incorrect

As suggested by the brilliant @jasonharper

> Just subtract each Y value from the height of the image before using it.

The code has been adjusted where

```
bottom = tess_boxes['bottom'][idx]
top = tess_boxes['top'][idx]
```

became

```
bottom = h-tess_boxes['bottom'][idx]
top = h-tess_boxes['top'][idx]
```

where "h" is the height of the image ( w,h = input_image.size )

The result is as desired where the boxes wrap around the target characters.

[image: Bounding boxes around image contents]

Thank you @jasonhaper